# How can I create file tree of my files in my hard drive through JQuery FileTree (ruby on rails)?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to connect JQuery [Filetree](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/#demo)  to my hard drive on a rails application. I did some research and found out that for security reasons JQuery can't access the hard drive directories, however, I was curious about how to make this work, perhaps with their Ruby connector?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is sandboxed, so it can't access user's drives or environments. It's a security and privacy change that was made years ago.

If you want to display that information, you have to capture it in another language that does have those privileges, and pass it into JavaScript, where it can access it. This is a common problem for web development.

Use Ruby's built-in [`Dir`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html) class to gather the information you want. It has a couple ways you can grab the entire disk hierarchy or a subset of it. In particular, check these methods: [`[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D), [`each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-i-each), [`glob`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob), and [`entries`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-entries).

Once you have the information you want in an array, convert it to a JSON string and embed that string into your JavaScript as a JavaScript string variable in your view, or, write a handler to retrieve that data on the fly via a URL.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got it to display my entire project directory, still working on accessing territory outside of that.